# Solved: HTML/PHP : Prevent Submit button from refreshing the page

Tags: php, html, button, refresh, form-submit

I am new to Web design and trying to set up an apache server on my raspberry pi to observe some status data.

I tried following basic html/php button example for a beginning.

[GeeksForGeeks html/html button example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button/)

But the page is always refreshed when I press a button.

I tried google, but all proper solution I could find are javascript related.

Can somebody help?

Comment: That's because the only possible solutions to this are, in fact, JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: Stopping the page from beeing refreshed on button press

Comment: I guess you are using form element. If you are using form tag like <form></form>
then you have to do one thing and it will not refresh. Write 
<form onsubmit='return false'>Your button and other stuff</form>
but mind it, it will not do anything else also as form is not submitting, so no server request is sent, so no output will be shown.

Comment: @JustMe please post us your code so we can see what those bad buttons do

Comment: What else should a submit button do?

Comment: Nothing, just trigger the php function.

Comment: I will just go with javascript ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

php is a server side script  and can only be effected when the page loads from database and as such the page must reload